# Div tag has a 16px margin at the top after 'position: fixed;'

Tags: html, css, css-position, margin, fixed

I have a header section along the top of my site which I want to stay fixed when people scroll down the page. The background of the header is black against a plain white background.

After adding in the `position:fixed;` rule it seems to add a margin of about 16px between the top of the page.

```
#container-id-01 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

I've tried changing the `margin` to `float:left;` but it still doesn't make any difference. The `width: 100%;` needs to be a percentage to fill the full width of the page.

Is there anyway to get rid of the margin?

Comment: Could you share the relevant html as well?

Comment: If you want your header at the top, it most likely will need `top:0;` in combination with `position:fixed`

Comment: And if you didn't use clear styles like :
maring: 0,
padding: 0 to reset default styles, then for example chrome will add margin: 8px by default.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `!important` didn't work, and the body was already set to `padding:0;`

I took advice from a commenter and `top:0;` did the trick

:)

Answer (score 0):

May be some style is overriding your current css make sure no other css is there for that element or you can do.

```
#container-id-01 {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000;
margin-top: 0px!important;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px!important;
position: fixed;
}
```

this will override all other styles..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might be the default body padding.

```
body{padding: 0px;}
```